# What's the longer-valve, metal-ring inner tube style called?

Tags: innertube, valves

I have an innertube for a Chariot stroller that apparently came from Europe, and the local bike shop people couldn't find one in their catalogs that was both the right size and having the thing I'm trying to describe.  I want to search for it myself but don't know what it's called.  It's a longer than normal valve, and has a washer-like thing (metal, but thicker than a washer, and threaded) that you spin down the valve until it locks the valve in place to the rim.  (We need one because we're going through innertubes like crazy--whenever you pump up a Chariot with the compact style pump we have, it wears the crap out of the valve.)  They could find it in the skinny Presta valve diameter but not in the standard valve diameter.

What's it called?  (And if you happen to know, where in Canada can I order one?)

Thanks,
Kev

Comment: are you talking about presta valves?

Comment: No, they actually did have Presta in that size with that valve.  We want the standard one instead.  (Ironic, because Presta's European, isn't it?  So it's easier to get American parts in Europe and vice-versa, it seems...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see some images of alternative valves at the [Schwalbe](http://www.schwalbetires.com/tech_info/valve) page. 
Your local bike shop is certainly familiar with Schraeder (aka "Auto") and Presta (aka Sclaverand) valves.  It's difficult to tell from your description, but it's therefore likely either a Regina or a Dunlop valve.

Comment: Thank you!  It's an auto valve with a *rim nut* that I'm looking for.

Comment: Probably your best bet is to get a [grommet](http://www.amazon.com/RIM-GROMMET-SVtoPV-ADAPTER-RUBBER/dp/B0013FCLCG) for converting Schraeder to Presta and then install a Presta valve, if you can find one of those that's the right dimensions.  The Presta, of course, has the full-length threading.

Comment: @Kev also check the info about valve tear off on the page linked to in the answer, to help you with going through less tubes. Some tips are to not tighten the rim nut too much, use the correct pressure (not too low) etc. Also, I find pumps that attach via a hose rather than directly can be easier on the valve, like [these](http://www.topeak.com/products/Morph-Pumps) or almost all [Lezyne pumps](http://www.lezyne.com/hand-pumps) attach via a hose, or an el-cheapo pump with a hose (like most pumps used to be).